# How to clean JSON data that contains \n and unnecessary spaces and is ill formatted, in python?

Tags: python, json, data-cleaning

I'm using this to get the data from pcpp in json format and I want to store the result in a file.

```
from pcpartpicker import API
import json

api = API("in")

categories = list(api.supported_parts)

parts = {}
for cat in categories[:2]:
    part = api.retrieve(cat).to_json()
    parts[cat] = []
    parts[cat].append(part)
    print(parts[cat])

# with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
#     json.dump(parts, outfile)
```

But, when I see the json it is like this:

```
\n        {\n            "brand": "Tripp Lite",\n            "model": "TE600",\n            "watt_capacity": 425,\n            "va_capacity": 600.0,\n            "price": [\n                "INR",\n                "0.00"\n            ]\n        }\n    ]\n}']
```

Now, I want to remove these \n and all these un-necessary spaces so that it is nice and understandable.
Any help?

Comment: The `\n` are newline characters... if you'll save it to a file this will be replaced by 'enters' more or less and you'll see it will look very nice!

Comment: That is what is not happening

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are converting to json with the line `part = api.retrieve(cat).to_json()` and then converting again with the commented out code.
Usually, you want to build up the data structure without conversion. Then once the data structure is complete, convert it all to json.

So your code would be:

```
from pcpartpicker import API
import json

api = API("in")

categories = list(api.supported_parts)

parts = {}
for cat in categories[:2]:
    part = api.retrieve(cat)
    parts[cat] = []
    parts[cat].append(part)

with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(parts, outfile)
```

Comment: `ExternalHDD(brand='Western Digital', model='easystore', type='Desktop', interface='USB 3.0', capacity=Bytes(total=8000000000000), price_per_gb=<Money: 4.860 INR>, color=None, price=<Money: 38879.00 INR>)]}]` This is what is looks without to_json() which gives an error that it is not json serializable

Comment: Not all data is JSON serializable. Specifically, in your example, the "Money" data type is blocking serialization because that data type is not directly representable in JSON format.